# Angular Lazyload routes generates extra chunk files with prefix default~pages

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to implement lazy loading routes for the project I'm currently working on. everything works and I get no errors, I can also see when I go to new pages new chunk files load.

however, in addition to my expected chunk files, cli also creates few extra files with prefix "default~pages", such as

```
default~pages-managers--managers-module~pages-hosts-hosts-module~pa~0e1f5bc0
```

and these files with `default~` prefix load regardless of what page I'm landing on.
For example, if I'm on the home page, I see both:

```
pages-home-home-module
```

and

```
default~pages-managers--managers-module~pages-hosts-hosts-module~pa~0e1f5bc0
```

does anyone know what are these default files are and how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 6):

Hope this helps:

I had the same issue that commonChunks with `default~ ....` where generated.

use in your `angular.json` (where you have `"aot": true` ... etc.):

`"commonChunk": false`

Answer (score 6):

This comment is w.r.t. Angular version `11.2.1`...

This is a default feature (set to `true`) that could be configured in `angular.json` file (Andre Elrico has already answered it), but I see a great benefit of keeping this default (i.e. bundle size(s) to load on the Network and build times). Below is a demonstration: -

With a common chunk: -
[image]

Without a common chunk: -
[image]

Outro: I can say- with the 2nd approach, common modules will get merged with each individual lazy-loaded module. If that is what you are looking for; then tweak the settings in `angular.json` file.

Please Note: The build time is dependant on the Operating System, Hardware Config, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something you should be worried about. This behavior is normal when you have `"optimization": false` in angular.json on build process. If you want to optimize your build. add `"optimization": true` in angular.json with following nesting `projects->{your project name}-architect->build->configurations->production`. In production object, you should add `"optimization": true` and after you run `ng build --configuration=production` it will work as expected.

I assume you were running only `ng build` or `ng build --watch` which by default doesn't have optimizer enabled so in that case, if you want to enable it and get rid of default chunk, you should add it to `projects->{your project name}-architect->build`. In build object, add `"optimization": true`.

Note: adding this to build process for watch and not production build will slow down your build drastically so i advise you to keep it enabled only on prod builds.

Comment: I don't think this is related to optimization since it was already set to true at the time i posted the question. later I figured out the new version of cli is actually smart enough to separate the repeated codes for lazy loading and place them inside those chunks named ~default.. , but there is not much info about it online

Comment: Not sure, had this issue on angular 7 and as soon i enabled optimization it stoped compiling that additional module... Just shared my experience.