# Application is generating a chunk of my lazy load module with prefix default ~ .. even before its getting invoked

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, chunks

I have implemented lazy-loading in my Angular Application (using CLI 7.3.4)

Its compiling successfully but when I route to a lazy-loaded module (say module1 path), its loading one more chunk which is actually other lazy loaded module (Module2) path.

Chunk Name:
"../default~lazy-load-modules-module1-module1-module~lazy-load-modules-module2-mo~be6d77c5.js"

I am unable to understand why this default ~ is getting generated.

I am expecting to load modules only when one of its component is invoked.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: please share some code I think you are missing something here.

Comment: Hello,
I appreciate your response. I am trying to create a stackblitz as I cant share my code. But unfortunately, I couldn't.

I found a duplicate of my question which is however not yet answered.

Please help me answering this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55944294/angular-lazyload-routes-generates-extra-chunk-files-with-prefix-defaultpages). It would help me.

Regards,
Akhil

Comment: Hello,

I have tried doing prod build with namedChunks: true.

js files generated after prod build :

default~lazy-load-modules-module1-module1-module-ngfactory~lazy-load-modules-module2~f905bd40.e57cb63c897b03f07599.js

default~lazy-load-modules-module2-module2-module-ngfactory~lazy-load-modules-m~e4585478.7b99f3d4bf5e27b58bfd.js

and 3 seperate js files for 3 seperate modules.

PS: I have having a shared module which is getting imported only in 2 modules out of 3, is this the reason for getting default ~ generated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its just means the generated chunk belongs to both module1 and module2.

I believe you had an shared module. If yes, then this is chunk of that module.

Please let me know if you want further information.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: @NikhilYadav: Below is the answer detail. I am not using any Shared module in this case.

Answer (score 4):

This comment is w.r.t. Angular version `11.2.1`...

This is a default feature (set to `true`) that could be configured in `angular.json` file (`commonChunk: false`, add this property below the `aot` key). Also, I see a great benefit of keeping the default value (improving bundle size(s) to load on the Network and build times). Below is a demonstration: -

With a common chunk: -
[image]

Without a common chunk: -
[image]

Outro: I can say- with the 2nd approach, common modules will get merged with each individual lazy-loaded module. If that is what you are looking for; then tweak the settings in `angular.json` file.

Please Note: The build time is dependant on the Operating System, Hardware Config, etc.